# SMTP-EXIM Help- Only sending single mail at a time

Tags: email, smtp, linux-server, exim

I would like to understand what could be the problem as to why I am unable to send mail to more that one recipient at a time. My mail server uses exim and I have the following configuration

```
smtp_accept_queue_per_connection = 0  
remote_max_parallel = 15   
smtp_receive_timeout = 165s  
ignore_bounce_errors_after = 1 d  
rfc1431_query_timeout = 0s  
timeout_frozen_after = 5d   
que_run_max = 10  
deliver_queue_load_max = 72  
queue_only_load = 144   
daemon_smtp_ports = 25:465:587   
tls_on_connect_ports = 465  
smtp_accept_max = 100    
smtp_connect_backlog= 50
```

Now I am not sure what this is supposed to result out as.but trying

```
telnet myserver.com 25
```

and got "we do not authorise the use of this system to transport unsolicited and or bulk email"
I am able to send single mail at a time. So someone please help me fix thix or guide me in what I am supposed to look for to fix this.
Thank you

Comment: The settings of the server are designed to prevent the sending methods common to bulk emailers, spammers. In order to send bulk email you have to utilize a server designed to handle that, with the appropriate trust mechanisms to prevent it from being misused and therefore blocked.

Comment: Thnks you for your response.Actually I too thought so. but that doesn't solve my problem. I am still unable to send mail to more than one recipient. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are there no setting that I can change so mail would be delivered to more than one recipient.?

Comment: Is this your own server that you are trying to learn how to manage and configure, or are you paying for or using a service on a third-party mail server?